# Compiler errors when including setupapi.h in hello world app

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to debug some C# P/Invoke problem with 32/64 bit using the [SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetdeviceinterfacedetaila) function. This involves analysing the [SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/ns-setupapi-sp_device_interface_detail_data_a) structure. For this, I tried to write a simple C++ program to see the data that's not documented. My C skills aren't sufficient to read the structure sizes from the definitions.

Here's the code for a new C++ Windows console application created with Visual Studio 2017:

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Setupapi.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Size: " << sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA) << "\n";
}
```

As soon as I add the third include, I get 1600+ compiler errors about syntax errors within Microsoft files – missing semicolons, type specifiers and other stuff, spreading over several files like setupapi.h, prsht.h, dpa_dsa.h or commctrl.h. That's well outside my capabilities. Looks like Microsoft has delivered a huge mess. Wondering how Visual Studio was compiled if C++ programming is always like this.

What's wrong here? Why can't I just include that header file as suggested in the documentation?

Is there another way to find out what that `sizeof` expression would resolve to?

Comment: `#include <windows.h>` before `#include <Setupapi.h>`

Comment: @RichardCritten Thanks, that helped. I could accept it if it was an answer instead of a comment. How should I know this?

Comment: Am not sure how you should know this (without some research).  From experience: all common type definitions are in `<windows.h>` header file.  Additional header files for specific functionality don't redefine the common types they instead need <windows.h> included 1st to provide them.

Comment: @ygoe ”How should I know this?” By reading output of the compiler. See Output IDE panel, switch the “Show output from” dropdown to “Build”. The first error you’re getting without <windows.h> points to this line in SetupAPI.h: `typedef GUID *LPGUID;` The `GUID` identifier has wavy red underline, move mouse there and you’ll see a tooltip saying “identifier GUID is undefined”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fixed version:

```
#include <iostream>
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <Setupapi.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Size: " << sizeof( SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA ) << "\n";
}
```

It prints 6, however that's not true, unfortunately for you that structure is variable-length. It's defined like this:

```
#define ANYSIZE_ARRAY 1
struct SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA_W
{
    DWORD  cbSize;
    WCHAR  DevicePath[ ANYSIZE_ARRAY ];
}
```

The length varies depending on data.

Comment: That's okay, I need the value of `sizeof` because that's what must be put in the `cbSize` field. When using this API from C# I have to convert the relevant structures to managed code that behaves exactly the same, no matter what it means. I wasn't sure if the array counts by content or denotes a pointer. Also, `ANYSIZE_ARRAY` didn't make sense to me and the value was unclear.